# Passing an argument to multiple commands in a single line

Tags: command-line

I'd like to be able to run multiple commands on the same file in a single line. The way I currently do this is:

```
commandA file && commandB file && perl -ne '...' file
```

My gut instinct tells me that there should be a way to provide the filename argument only once and pipe it to both commands simultaneously through `xargs` or something similar:

```
find file | xargs commandA && xargs commandB && xargs perl -ne '...'
```

When I try this, only the first command runs. How can I achieve what I want to do?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define a local variable for this:

```
f=file; commandA $f && commandB $f && ...
```

You can also execute all unconditionally (replacing `&&` with `;`) or in parallel (replacing `&&` with `&`).

Alternatively, you can also use shell history expansion to reference previous arguments:

```
commandA file && commandB !:1 && ...
```

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind, but is an interesting alternative.

Comment: What is wrong with this answer?

Comment: This is really cool! Is there a way not defining a new variable?

Comment: @user, I've added an alternative.

Answer (score 9):

For shells such as Bash, Korn and Z that have process substitution, you can do this:

```
find file | tee >(xargs commandA) >(xargs commandB) >(xargs perl -ne '...')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use xargs to construct a command line e.g.:

```
echo file | xargs -i -- echo ls -l {}\; wc -l {}
```

Just pipe the above into bash to run it:

```
echo file | xargs -i -- echo ls -l {}\; wc -l {} | bash
```

Extending the example to all the *.c files in the current directory (escaping the *ls* here to prevent any shell alias substitution):

```
\ls -1 *.c | xargs -i -- echo ls -l {}\; wc -l {} | bash
```

Comment: Used this to get a listing of all of files contained in directories where the name is like "enums":

    `find . -name "*enums*" | xargs -i echo -e echo {}\; ls -lh {}\; echo -e '\n\n' | bash`

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't vote for this myself. It's silly and dangerous, but just in the interest of listing the ways to do this, there's:

`for cmd in "commandA" "commandB" "perl -ne '...'" ; do eval $cmd file ; done`